# Registering an MBeanServerConnection as an MBean in an MBeanServer

Tags: jmx, mbeans

I thought it would be useful to aggregate the remote MBeanServers that a JMX aggregation server has connected, but I found that registering the MBeanServerConnection as an MBean in an MBeanServer throws a non compliant MBean exception.

Surely someone must have done this before and thus I was wondering if there's a standard way of accomplishing this.  I can, of course, create the required dynamic MBean or some wrapper for the MBeanServerConnection, but - as I said - surely this must be a something that has been solved before, hopefully in a standard package.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.  Not really standard (AFAIK), but has been solved with a [cascading, or federation of MBeanServers](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/federating_mbeanservers_with_opendmk)  More sophisticated than I wanted, but provides the functionality I needed.